# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, fedora, selinux

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled in fedora 28

Comment: Please try to add more context or steps to reproduce also explain your environment. Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ /usr/sbin/getenforce
enforcing
```

- edit /etc/selinux/config

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#       targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#       mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

- reboot server

```
$ /usr/sbin/getenforce
Disabled
```