# OCI runtime error for Docker on Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I am superficially familiar with docker and know a bit about linux but my current situation has me out of depth.
I am repurposing an older laptop (Thinkpad T540p) to host a few network services via docker. I was able to install and run docker on it using the previous OS (Ubuntu 18 or 20 LTS), tested using `docker run hello-world`.
After that I reinstalled the laptop, now using Debian Bullseye. I ran `apt update && apt upgrade` after installing to ensure an up to date system and installed docker. When I ran `docker run hello-world` however, an error occurred that I have been unable to debug.
Some info:

```
root@machine:$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: process_linux.go:458: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: can't load program: operation not permitted: unknown.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled

root@machine:$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289

root@machine:$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye

root@machine:$ uname -a
Linux machine 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have been looking around for issues containing a similar error to mine and found

- https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/2167 (CloudLinux with cgroups/procHooks error)
- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1183 (slightly different but system capability mismatch or something like that)
- [docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855240/docker-error-response-from-daemon-oci-runtime-create-failed)

All seeming to point towards some kind of Seccomp/AppArmor setting that is blocking Docker from starting, but I have no clue what to change in order to get it working. The terms AppArmor and Seccomp were random jargon to me 2 days ago so I would rather not just go edit some system config file.

Clues on what is going wrong or what to change are very much appreciated.